How to declare a function that returns a char[][]?
I have a program that tries to input a file and read it into RAM using sscanf.
However, I haven't even been able to test my logic because my compiler is throwing some errors that I believe all stem from the same mistake (either repeated in multiple places, or one spot failing caused a domino effect)
The problem stems from declaring a 2d array of chars to the heap by using:
char[][] swapKey;

(I'm using cygwin terminal btw)
I try to declare a function that has a return type of the same:
char[][] getKey() {

This throws an error:
swapCode.c:13:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
   13 | char[][] getKey() {
      |     ^

This seems like it thinks I didn't finish declaring the "char[][]"?
There are a couple errors of this same genre, so I'm going to include the entire file (only ~50 lines) because I don't know exactly where the issue stems from. I'll also include exactly what the compiler said in response to trying to compile:
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP_CODE_KEY "testSwapCodeKey.txt"

int changes;

void printSwapKey (char[][] swapKey) {
    for (int i = 0; i < changes; i++) {
        printf("%c=%c\n", swapKey[0], swapKey[1]);
    }
}

char[][] getKey() {
    FILE *file = fopen(SWAP_CODE_KEY, "r");
    if(file == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    char line[5];
    int lines = 0;

    if (sscanf(fgets(line, sizeof(line, file)), "changes=%d", changes) == 1) {
        printf("Succesfully retrieved number of changes from file: %d\n", changes);
    } else {
        printf("Failed to retrieve number of changes from file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    char[changes][1] swapKey;
    for (int i = 0; i < changes; i++) {
        swapKey[i][0] = "";
        swapKey[i][1] = "";
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) || lines >= changes) {
        lines++;
        char originalCharacter = "";
        char swappedCharacter = "";
        if (sscanf(line, "%c=%c", originalCharacter, swappedCharacter) == 2) {
            printf("Trying to add line to swapKey at line %d\n", lines);
            swapKey[lines][0] = originalCharacter;
            swapKey[lines][1] = swappedCharacter;
            printf("Added line to swapKey at line %d\n", lines);
        } else {
            printf("Failed to scan line at line %d", lines);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    return swapKey;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    char[][] swapKey = getKey();
    printSwapKey (swapKey);
}

And the compiler:

<myName> <myName>Laptop ~
$ cc swapCode.c -Wall
swapCode.c:7:24: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘char[]’
    7 | void printSwapKey (char[][] swapKey) {
      |                        ^
swapCode.c:7:24: note: declaration of multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
swapCode.c:7:29: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘swapKey’
    7 | void printSwapKey (char[][] swapKey) {
      |                             ^~~~~~~
swapCode.c:13:5: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
   13 | char[][] getKey() {
      |     ^
swapCode.c: In function ‘main’:
swapCode.c:55:9: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
   55 |     char[][] swapKey = getKey();
      |         ^
swapCode.c:56:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printSwapKey’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   56 |     printSwapKey (swapKey);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
swapCode.c:56:19: error: ‘swapKey’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   56 |     printSwapKey (swapKey);
      |                   ^~~~~~~
swapCode.c:56:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

<myName> <myName>Laptop ~
$

I'm sorry for how vague this question is, but I've spent about 1.3 hours just staring at this and not getting any closer.

You cannot, as there is no such type.

"I believe all stem from the same mistake" You are correct. "This seems like it thinks I didn't finish declaring the "char[][]"?" You are correct again. You didn't. "declaring a 2d array of chars to the heap by using: char[][] swapKey;" No, that doesn't do anything on the heap and is not a correct array definition as it is missing the required array dimensions and you can't return arrays that way. You can get at least part of what you want by using VLAs, but won't be able to do that for the function return type.

char[changes][1] swapKey; should be char swapKey[changes][2];. But you won't be able to use it as the return value of the function since you 1) can't return arrays from a function and 2) it is a local variable and does not continue to exist after the function exits. There are a couple of ways to approach this, but it seems like there are serious flaws in your learning materials and you desperately need to replace them with something better.


sizeof(line, file) is the same as sizeof(file).  2) Try fgets(line, sizeof(line, file)) --> fgets(line, sizeof line, file).


Note that I had deleted my answer after noticing that it does not fully answer your question. Meanwhile, I have expanded my answer, so I have now undeleted it.

@AviBerger Ik it's broken for other reasons, but isn't it valid that way? I wanted a 'changes' by 2 array, and since it's in C, 0 counts as an index.

Yes, 0 counts as an index. The definition doesn't give the maximum index value, but the quantity. So char swapKey[changes][2]; would be a changes by 2 array with valid first index values from 0 to changes - 1 and valid second index values from 0 to 1. ``char swapKey[changes][1];is changes by 1 and only has 0 as a valid second index, soswapKey[i][1]` would be an out-of bounds access as it attempts to access the second of only one item .

@AviBerger Is there a reason that it starts at zero in most other cases, but in declaration it assumes literal quantity?

Returning an array from a function
In C, it is not possible to return an array from a function. Therefore, the function declaration
char[][] getKey() {

is wrong.
However, it is possible for the calling function to pass a pointer to the start of an array and for the called function to modify the content of the array using that pointer, so that the calling function can then access the new content of the array. For example:
#include <stdio.h>

void write_array( char *arr, size_t arr_size )
{
    snprintf( arr, arr_size, "%s", "banana" );
}

int main( void )
{
    // make array large enough to store both "apple"
    // and "banana"
    char text[7] = "apple";

    printf( "Text before function call: %s\n", text );
    write_array( text, sizeof text );
    printf( "Text  after function call: %s\n", text );
}

This program will print the following:
Text before function call: apple
Text  after function call: banana

Declaring an array without specifying its size
The line
char[][] swapKey = getKey();

is incorrect.
In C, the size of an array cannot be changed after creating the array, so you must specify its size when creating it.
However, it is permissible to not specify the size of the array if its size is implied by the initializer. For example, if you write
int arr[] = { 5, 6, 7 };

then the array has a size of 3, because you initialized it with 3 elements.
But when initializing a 2D array, only the size of the outer array may be implied; the size of the inner array must be explicitly specified. For example:
int arr[][3] =
{
    {  5,  6,  7 },
    {  8,  9, 10 },
    { 11, 12, 13 },
    { 14, 15, 16 }
};

In this case, the size of the outer array is implied to be 4, but the size of the inner array must be explicitly specified to be 3.
Passing a multidimensional array to a function
The function declaration
void printSwapKey (char[][] swapKey) {

is wrong.
In C, it is not possible to directly pass an array to a function. When a function is declared to take an array as a parameter, the compiler automatically converts the parameter's data type to a pointer to an element of the array.
For example, in one of the previous sections, I used the following function declaration:
void write_array( char *arr, size_t size )

I could also have written the following:
void write_array( char arr[], size_t size )

In this case, the compiler would have automatically converted the char [] parameter to char *. It is not necessary to specify the size of the array, because this information is discarded anyway.
However, this does not apply to multidimensional arrays. A multidimensional array is nothing else than an array of arrays. If you declare a function to accept a multidimensional array as a parameter, then, as mentioned above, the compiler will automatically convert the parameter to a pointer to an element of the (outer) array. Therefore, the compiler will convert the parameter to a pointer to an (inner) array. For example, if you specify int arr[4][3] as the parameter, then the compiler will convert this parameter to int (*arr)[3] (pointer to array of 3 elements of type int).
Since only the outer dimension of the multidimensional array is discarded, you can only omit specifying the size of the outer array, but not the size of the inner array. That is why your function declaration is wrong.

Good 'nuff, but... Recommend avoiding "size" as, too often, newbies will struggle to comprehend the difference between "number of elements" and "number of bytes" when dealing with an array... "Size" is too generic, and, imho, should be avoided...

"automatically converts the parameter's data type to a pointer to an element of the array" -> "automatically converts the parameter's data type to a pointer to the first element of the array" would be more accurate IMHO.

@babon: All elements of an array have the same data type. Therefore, it does not matter in this context. However, you are correct that when actually passing an array to a function, the array will decay to a pointer to the first element of the array.

@AndreasWenzel Agreed, the data type will be same. Just wanted to point out what to expect when dereferencing.

@Fe2O3: I agree that this is a problem. However, "size" is such a nice short word, and using it is not technically wrong ("size in elements" vs. "size in bytes"). I could change the identifier arr_size to arr_num_elements, but that would make it a bit too long in my opinion. And if I use the identifier arr_size, then I want to use the term "size" in the rest of my text for consistency. I wish there were another term I could use that is be less ambiguous and still nice and short. However, I'm afraid that the term "length" is not much better than "size", as it is also ambiguous.

@AndreasWenzel It's for each to choose their own conventions. I understand what you've written, but I've a bit of experience. If/when I'm conscious of needing/wanting to make the distinction clear, I use flavours of nElem and nBytes (or something similar.) All good... Just commenting... Cheers! :-)... (PS: Usually crops up in functions where lifetimes of variables is fleeting and local... Brevity (with comment, if desired) aids in quickly "scanning and grokking" :-)...

@AndreasWenzel Just checked my C doco. fread() uses var names count & size, and calloc() uses num and size... My conclusion, from those two cases, is that size should be used as "number of bytes". For functions receiving an array (of elements of known "size"), another name should be used to indicate how many elements are in the array... Just passing the time... :-) Cheers!

@Fe2O3: I just noticed that in the C++ standard library, std::vector::size returns the size of the vector in elements, not in bytes. Therefore, I'm afraid that this war is already lost.
